# Foundation 3 - customForms checkbox`es/radio buttons don't work when loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Foundation 3.

And I'm having a problem with custom forms and javascript. I use reveal plugin for login and signup forms. if I load forms statically into HTML everything works fine. But if I load them dynamically (lets say ajax), check boxes and radio buttons don't work. Even after reviel I call "$.foundation.customForms.appendCustomMarkup". What should I do? I really like those custom checkboxes and radio buttons. How could I use them with dynamically loaded HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago -- but incase anyone else comes across it, here's how you do it:

Let's say the container that your `ajax` is loaded in is `<div id="myModal"></div>`

After, your content is loaded, you've got to fire `$('#myModal).foundation('forms');`